# $(\pi )\cap \mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$ where $\pi$ is a prime element in quadratic integer ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying the factorization in the Gaussian integers.

However, I have trouble in understanding below statement.

$(\pi )\cap \mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$ where $\pi$ is a prime element in quadratic integer ring.

How can I prove this?

Comment: *Hint*: Show $(\pi) \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. What do prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ look like?

Comment: Thank you! I got it for your nice advice

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Feel free to post your answer below.